# No se inserta valor select en php mvc ajax

Tags: php, ajax, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de insertar los datos desde un select pero no me ingresa ni me da error, la lista e carga sin problemas pero no se inserta

la vista del select donde me carga la tabla programas

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" name="materia_programa_reg">
                                <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Seleccione un programa</option>
                                <?php
                                 require_once "./controladores/materiaControlador.php";
                                 $ins_materia = new materiaControlador();
                                 echo $ins_materia->listar_programa_controlador();
                                 ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

Este es el controlador para hacer la lista y llenarla en la vista

```
public function listar_programa_controlador(){
                $programa="";
                $consulta="SELECT * FROM programa";

                 $conexion = mainModel::conectar();
                $datos = $conexion->query($consulta);

                       foreach($datos as $rows){
                        $programa.='
                        <option value="'.$rows['programa_id'].'">'.$rows['programa_nombre'].'</option>';
                       }

             return $programa; 

            }
```

y el controlador para agregar una materia donde debo registrar el nombre de la materia y al programa al cual pertenece

```
public function agregar_materia_controlador(){

            $nombre=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['materia_nombre_reg']);

            $programa=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['materia_programa_reg']);


                    $datos_materia_reg=[
                        "Nombre"=>$nombre,
                        "Programa"=>$programa
                    ];

                    $agregar_materia=materiaModelo::agregar_materia_modelo($datos_materia_reg);
                    if($agregar_materia->rowCount()==1){
                        $alerta=[
                            "Alerta"=>"limpiar",
                            "Titulo"=>"Materia Registrado",
                            "Texto"=>"Datos ingresados con exito",
                            "Tipo"=>"success"
                        ];

                    echo json_encode($alerta);

        }
```

Comment: No logro entender la lógica de tu programa. ¿Qué acción lanza la inserción? ¿Depuraste los objetos para ver lo que están devolviendo? ¿Cuál fue el resultado de esa depuración? O, ¿depurar te suena a chino? Si es así, es algo que conviene que aprendas, porque saber depurar te ahorrará horas y horas rompiéndote el coco.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me vota este error:
 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Ese error es en el cliente (¿Javascript?)  Puede que tenga que ver con algo del servidor, pero son dos cosas distintas. Lo que parece indicar es que el cliente está recibiendo un JSON inválido. Depura lo que recibes en el cliente mostrándolo en la consola.